# Vulkan compute shader. Smooth uv coordinates

Tags: vulkan, compute-shader

I have this shader:

```
#version 450

layout(binding = 0) buffer b0 {
  vec2 src[ ];
};

layout(binding = 1) buffer  b1 {
   vec2 dst[ ];
};

layout(binding = 2) buffer b2 {
  int index[ ];
};

layout (local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;


void main()
{
    int ind =int(gl_GlobalInvocationID.x);
    vec2 norm;

    norm=src[index[ind*3+2]]-src[index[ind*3]]+src[index[ind*3+1]]-src[index[ind*3]];
    norm/=2.0;

    dst[index[ind*3]]  +=norm;

    norm=src[index[ind*3+0]]-src[index[ind*3+1]]+src[index[ind*3+2]]-src[index[ind*3+1]];

    dst[index[ind*3+1]]  +=norm;

    norm=src[index[ind*3+1]]-src[index[ind*3+2]]+src[index[ind*3+0]]-src[index[ind*3+2]];
    norm/=2.0;

    dst[index[ind*3+2]]  +=norm;

 }
```

Because dst buffer is not "atomic", the summation is incorrect.

Is there any way to solve this problem? My answer is no, but if i missed something.

For each vertex in polygon I am calculating a vector from vertex to the center of polygon. Different polygons has the same vertices.

dst - is a vertex buffer, the result of the summation of those shifts from vertex to polygon center.

Each time I have different computation results.

Comment: There's not enough information in this question to answer it. It's not clear why it would need to be "atomic", since you're not overwriting anything in `dst` from one compute shader dispatch operation. Each invocation should be getting a different `index`, so they all ought to be writing to different memory addresses. Unless you're executing a second CS that also accesses these addresses without proper synchronization, there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Different invocations can add value to the same dst index.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the indirection. Then... make them atomic adds. What's the problem?

Comment: atomicAdd is working, but I have to convert floats to ints and then back to floats for later use. Is there any way to avoid this?